# Реализовать анимацию через transition и animation

Tags: css, css-animation

---

Требуется создать анимацию к объекту квадрат: цвет последовательно меняется (красный – синий – зеленый – коричневый – фиолетовый – красный).

Реализовать это требуется двумя способами, через *transition* и *animation*.

Второе сделал в `@keyframes`:

```css
@keyframes sq {
    0% {
        background-color: red;
    }
    20% {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    40% {
        background-color: green;
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    }
    60% {
        background-color: brown;
        transform: skew(-45deg, 45deg);
    }
    80% {
        background-color: violet;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

А вот `transition` не нахожу соответствующей информации.

Такая анимация для первого свойства возможна?

Полный текст задания:

> Объект: квадрат. Цвет постепенно меняется в последовательности:
> красный – синий – зеленый – коричневый – фиолетовый – красный. Во
> второй половине анимации добавляется поворот против часовой стрелки по
> оси Y и положительный наклон по оси Z.

Comment: Вы, шпион? Зачем Вы задаёте такие вопросы, предоставляя минимум информации? Например, цвет чего - текста или фона?

Comment: сейчас дополню описание

Comment: смена цвета - плавная или дискретная?

Comment: слово "постепенно" я понимаю как "плавная"

Answer (score 0):

- `transitions` – для простых анимаций, завязанных на `:hover`;
- `animations` – для сложных покадровых анимаций через `@keyframes`.

```css
.circle {
  background: red;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  animation: sq 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes sq {
    0% {
        background: red;
    }
    20% {
        background: blue;
    }
    40% {
        background: green;
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    }
    60% {
        background: brown;
        transform: skew(-45deg, 45deg);
    }
    80% {
        background: violet;
    }
    100% {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```